# Mosfet Td(on) and Td (off) must be equal

Tags: mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver

I am having a mosfet CSD13380F3

The problem I am having is that I need the Td(off) and Td (on) to match. In the datasheet they are specified at 4ns and 11ns

I am trying to make the 2 timings equal (needed for my design)

While researching I have found a formula :

Ig = Q/t

where Q is the gate charge in Coulomb (nC from the data sheet) and t is the switching time (in ns if you use nC).

So my calculation is I=0.082A . Is this formula correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy to manipulate the on and off switching times of a MOSFET independently.

First, get a repeatable setup, with a decent gate drive IC. A resistor between its output and the gate will control the switching time. It's common practice to put a few ohms to a few 10s of ohms here anyway to tidy up the interface.

Now replace that resistor with a larger resistor, shunted by the small resistor in series with a diode. The diode and small resistor will control the switching time in one direction, the larger resistor will control the switching time in the other. Adjust the large resistor value until you achieve your times, you may need to reverse the diode if you can't achieve equality.

Comment: I dont need to touch the Td(off)...unless the load they drive (resistive but different value for each) will have an impact on the Td(off). I am planing to use a shift register like 74hc595 to drive the mosfets

Comment: several quaestions about the 595 to drive the FETs. Voltage? Current drive capacbility? A 595 won't get nS, you need to drive amps into the gate to get that. I know a gate is Mohms, but it's also nF, and to slew nF by 10v in 10nS needs amps, not the 10s of mA you'd get from a 595.

Comment: So each gate needs 0.08A as per my first calculation. From my understanding of the 595 datasheet each pin can suply 0.25ma per bit pin. I plan on using 4v